# POST to two APIs in one Controller

Tags: c#, .net, microservices

I'm asking this again because my original question didn't get an answer so I'm going to try and simplify it

I have a controller and two different solutions with one model each.

In one of the controllers (OrdersController) I want to post data which is sent to another model called Basket. I want to post the following to OrdersController:

```
{
  "identifier": "string"
}
```

which I want to send to my Basket model as well in the following url:

```
https://localhost:5500/api/Basket/{identifier}
```

Here is my controller in OrderControllers:

```
 [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult<OrderDTO>> PostOrderDTO(OrderDTO orderDTO)
        {
            // TODO Contact BasketService (GET /api/Baskets/{identifier} and take out 'identifier' and post to BasketService


            // Generate Order (Order, OrderLine)

            _context.OrderDTO.Add(orderDTO);
            try
            {
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateException)
            {
                if (OrderDTOExists(orderDTO.Identifier))
                {
                    return Conflict();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }

            return CreatedAtAction("GetOrderDTO", new { id = orderDTO.Identifier }, orderDTO);
        }
```

How do I do this?

Thanks in advance

Original question:
[Passing String from Database to Another Database in .NET (Microservices)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70533952/passing-string-from-database-to-another-database-in-net-microservices)

Comment: You can use `HttpClient` to send a request to another controller.

Comment: @PoulBak How do I do this? Like this ? using var httpResponseMessage =
                await httpClient.PostAsync("http://localhost:5700/api/OrderDTO", orderJson); Thanks for the help by the way

Comment: Here is a simple example: https://newbedev.com/javascript-httpclient-post-request-with-json-body-c-code-example.

Comment: When you use `HttpClient` you can send anything that the the receiving controller understands, including querystrings.

Comment: @PoulBak Thank you so much, I'm going to check it out and try it :)

Comment: @PoulBak Thank you so much my friend, may God bless you

Answer (score 0):

> If your controller name is "OrdersController" and controller is post,
> your url should be

```
https://localhost:5500/api/Orders
```

> You can not send a model to controller with queryString.

Comment: Yes my url to POST is /api/Orders but how do I send the "identifier" key to my other api as well? Thanks for helping out by the way

Comment: *You can not send a model to controller with queryString* - really?